# Changing add to cart button depending on category Id

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, catalog, addtocart

I have a category of products that can't be bought online directly but that I want to give the functionality of going to a distributors page.

For that, I need to retrieve the category id of the current product and if it's equal to 13 display a different content for the add to cart button.

So far, the code that I have is:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>

<?php $categoryId = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); ?>
<?php if ($categoryId == 13) {?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Find your nearest retailer') ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('distributors') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Find your nearest retailer') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
<?php }
    elseif ($_product->isSaleable()) { ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()){ ?>
            <div class="qty-wrapper v-center">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="paypal-wrapper"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Could you guys help me with getting this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what is the output for the code above, first ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId()`. This only works if you are on a certain category page, but you can view the product outside the category context.
You can get the category ids like this:

```
<?php $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();?>
```

Then check `if (in_array(13, $categoryIds)) {...}` and display your custom content.

But in my opinion relying on categories for product functionality is not the best approach.
I would add a new `yes/no` attribute on the products called `from_reseller`. set this attribute to be used in product listing, rebuild indexes and then just check  `if ($_product->getFromReseller()) {...}` and display your message.  It's cleaner this way.

Comment: That works right away. If I try the second suggestion with the attribute, do I have to put something like if ($_product->getFromReseller(true)) or just as you've suggested without anything?

Comment: You don't need the extra parameter.

Comment: what if I want to add an if statement that combines $_product->getFromReseller() and a specific customer group? I'm creating the variable out the if statement with `$_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
    if($_isLoggedIn === true){
        $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    }` and then doing  `elseif ($_product->getFromReseller() && $_myGroupId == 4)` but it's not working properly