# Change "add to cart" button depending on customer group and attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, addtocart, customer-group

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/changing-add-to-cart-button-depending-on-category-id) and the code is working fine. I can change the "add to cart" button depending on the value of a yes/no attribute.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to create an `if/elseif/elseif` statement, in which the if condition is the yes/no attribute, the first `elseif` condition is a joined statement of the `yes/no` and customer group, and the last `elseif` condition is the default `isSaleable()` condition.

The code that I have is as follows but it throws the error that the variable `$_myGroupId` isn't defined:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>

<!--getting the customer group like this works.-->
<?php $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
if($_isLoggedIn === true){
    $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
} ?>

<!--changing the content of the button according to the yes/no attribute also works without issues.-->
<?php if ($_product->getFromRetailer()) {?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Find your nearest retailer') ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('distributors') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Find your nearest retailer') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
<?php }

<!--this combined elseif statement with product attribute and customer group doesn't work.-->
elseif ($_product->getFromRetailer() && $_myGroupId == 3) { ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Look at me') ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('distributors') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Look at me') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
<?php }

<!--this default elseif statement works without issues.-->
elseif ($_product->isSaleable()) { ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()){ ?>
            <div class="qty-wrapper v-center">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="paypal-wrapper"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT** Just to make it clearer, I can get the customer group successfully and the problem that I have with the code is the statement `elseif ($_product->getFromRetailer() && $_myGroupId == 3)`. It throws the error that `$_myGroupId` isn't defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you just need to define a default value $_myGroupId above the if($_isLoggedIn) line

Comment: but what if in the future I want to make other `elseif` statements in this code for different customer groups?

Comment: then you just add them? the problem is that you're trying to access a variable that hasn't been declared yet (because apparently isLoggedIn is false). if you add a default value for myGroupId, for example 0, then you won't have an undefined variable

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It goes to the first `if ($_product->getFromRetailer())` statement.

Comment: that means that getFromRetailer returns true: then it executes that piece of code.. but your problem with the undefined variable is solved

Comment: so maybe is a matter of reversing the order of the statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Anja for giving me pointers that have allowed me to solve my issue.

In the end, it was a matter of the order of the `if/elseif/elseif` statements.

The code that works for me is as follows:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>

<?php $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
if($_isLoggedIn === true){
    $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
} ?>

<?php if ($_myGroupId == 3 && $_product->getFromRetailer()) { ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Get a quote') ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('quote') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Get a quote') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
<?php }

elseif ($_product->getFromRetailer()) {?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Find your nearest retailer') ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('distributors') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Find your nearest retailer') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
<?php }

elseif ($_product->isSaleable()) { ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart v-centered-content">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart v-center" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()){ ?>
            <div class="qty-wrapper v-center">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="paypal-wrapper"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
if($login) {
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    //do your thing shorty!
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already have that bit of code and I know that works, what I'm having problems with is the `elseif ($_product->getFromRetailer() && $_myGroupId == 3)` statement

Comment: That is not what you stated in your question. Please update it.

Comment: I put it there in the explanation, but I'll rewrite it anyway.